# convert STL list<string> into vector<string> c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

What's the best way to convert a list into a vector?

I was thinking about a loop.  But maybe there's a better way in C++11?

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

list<string> list_string {
  "one",
  "two",
  "three"
};

vector<string> vector_string;
for (auto item : list_string) {
    vector_string.push_back(item);
}
```

In C# I could just initialize the other data type using a constructor accepting IEnumerable interface.  Was curious if C++11 supports anything similar...

Answer (score 11):

One of the constructors for [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (and indeed, for any of the standard containers), takes a pair of iterators:

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So you can just do:

```
vector<string> v(list_string.begin(), list_string.end());
```

Comment: The only issue I have with this approach is that the number of items being added is not known ahead of time, especially for non-random-access iterators like from `std::list`.  So if performance is an issue, and you want to reduce reallocations while populating, it *might* be worth constructing an empty `vector` first, then `reserve()` the same size as the `std::list`, then finally populate the vector using a `push_back()` loop, or `std::copy(_n)()`, or the range-based `std:::vector::insert()`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau While not guaranteed by the standard, [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/1639392a4af6150c69d77bbda1327b2fbce8c293/include/vector#L1197-L1213) and [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/393138d71ac96666d06ec98d28e3f7346ddad287/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L524-L539) will preallocate the memory as long as the iterators are at least *ForwardIterator*s. Thus, you aren't going to get a bunch of unnecessary reallocations, but you will get an extra iteration through the container

Comment: I'd even recommend using std::move_iterator if list is not needed anymore in code: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy the elements to your vector:

```
vector<string> vector_string(list_string.size());
copy(begin(list_string), end(list_string), begin(vector_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

"Convert" is a little bit ambiguous.  First consider copying.  Because `list::size()` is O(1) as of C++11, a fairly efficient way to copy `list<string>` into `vector<string>` is:

```
vector<string> vector_string;
vector_string.reserve(list_string.size());
vector_string.assign(list_string.begin(), list_string.end());
```

If you don't need `list_string` anymore, you can improve efficiency (assuming sufficiently large strings that require a heap allocation) by using `std::move_iterator`, as in:

```
vector<string> vector_string;
vector_string.reserve(list_string.size());
vector_string.assign(move_iterator(list_string.begin()), move_iterator(list_string.end()));
```

which will avoid additional heap allocations by moving the strings.